# Iterate through file names

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to loop through file names that all have the same name with an incrementing number at the end. I have something like this as of right now:

```
 int i;
 NSString * imagename[i];
 for (i = 0; i < 49; i++) {
 photo = [MWPhoto photoWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]   pathForResource:imagename[i] ofType:@"jpg"]]];
        photo.caption = @"THIS IS AN IMAGE";
        [photos addObject:photo];
}
```

I have 50 images all with names like "imagename1, imagename2" etc.. so Instead of entering them all manually I just want to loop through them but I don't know the correct syntax to do so in ios.

Comment: Where are your files? Are in the application root or in the application data?

Comment: Since you're loading the files from your app bundle, you might be better off, putting all the images you want into a subfolder within the bundle, you could then just load all the images in that directory. No need to worry about the names or their number that way either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
    NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"imagename%d", i];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:@"jpg"];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
    MWPhoto *photo = [MWPhoto photoWithImage:image];
    photo.caption = @"Hi";
    [photos addObject:photo];
}
```

Don't cram everything onto one line. It's hard to read and debug.

Comment: Actually just came up with the same solution as you posted this :p thank you though.

Answer (score 3):

This will give you a sorted array of your images:

```
NSArray * imagePaths = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType: @"jpg" inDirectory: nil] sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSMutableArray * images = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSString * imagePath in imagePaths) {
    if ([imagePath rangeOfString: @"imagename"].location != NSNotFound) {
        [images addObject: [UIImage imageNamed: [imagePath lastPathComponent]]];
    }
}
```

No need to worry about the total number

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
int i;

 for (i = 0; i < 49; i++) 
{

 NSMutableString *tempImgStr = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"imagename%d.png", i+1];
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:tempImgStr]
 photo = [MWPhoto photoWithImage:image];
        photo.caption = @"THIS IS AN IMAGE";
        [photos addObject:photo];
}
```

Comment: No need to make the string mutable.

Comment: true, I personally like mutable string. Just my thing :-)